# Laravel4 with a database already created

Tags: php, mysql

Please I am new to Laravel4.

I have already created a mysql database and I have inserted some data into it too using MySQL Workbench.
As I read and tried multiple tutorials, I found that all tutorials create a new database and after that they use migrations and seeds to insert data but this is not my case.
Please can anyone tell me how to proceed if I have an already created and filled database?

Thanks & kind regards

Comment: Resolved No migrations :)

Comment: If there is any chance your system will be moving to a new database you actually should use migrations as it is easy to build entire database on a new system. It takes time though so I can imagine a local project and you would not want to invest time on writing migrations.